# SonarLint displaying issues only in files changes

Tags: sonarqube, static-code-analysis, sonarlint, sonarlint-vs

I'm looking to improve the code base of the department I'm working and I want to do it in a incremental way.
My idea is that I only want to be running SonarQube and SonarLint in the files that the developer is changing.
In sonarqube we have:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/06/02/sonarqube-code-analysis-issues-integration-into-pull-requests/

Is there a way to do the same in SonarLint?

With a code base with a big technical debt, if SonarLint is going to list the issues of all the current files and I only want to list the issues of the files that the user has changed.

Let me know your thoughts or any other way to achieve something similar

Answer (score 5):

This answer is not specific to SonarLint but to Visual Studio. In the "Error List" window there's a dropdown where you can select to only display issues in "Changed Documents".